# Spark read partitions - Resource cost analysis

Tags: performance, apache-spark, partitioning

When reading data partitioned by column in Spark with something like `spark.read.json("/A=1/B=2/C=3/D=4/E=5/")` will allow to scan only the files in the folder E=5.

But let's say I am interested to read partitions in which `C = my_value` through all the data source. The instruction will be `spark.read.json("/*/*/C=my_value/")`.

What happens computationally in the described scenario under the hood? Spark will just list through the partition values of A and B? Or it will scan through all the leaves (the actual files) too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for an interesting question. Apache Spark uses Hadoop's `FileSystem` abstraction to deal with wildcard patterns. In the source code they're called *glob patterns*

The `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem#globStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)` method is used to return "an array of paths that match the path pattern". This function calls then  `org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber#glob` to figure out the exact files matching algorithm for the glob pattern. globStatus is called by `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource#checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary`. You can add some breakpoints to see how does it work under-the-hood.

But long story short:

> What happens computationally in the described scenario under the hood? Spark will just list through the partition values of A and B? Or it will scan through all the leaves (the actual files) too?

Spark will split your glob in 3 parts ["*", "*", "C=my_value"]. Later, it will list files at every level by using Hadoop `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem#listStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)` method. For every file it will build a path and try to match it against the current pattern. The matching files will be kept as "candidates" that will be filtered out only at the last step, when the algorithm will look for "C=my_value".

Unless you have a lot of files, this operation shouldn't hurt you. And probably that's one of the reasons why you should rather keep less but bigger files (famous data engineering problem of "too many small files").

Comment: And for S3 then?

Comment: The algorithm is the same. The difference is the used implementation of `FileSystem` to list or detect files, which for S3 should be `NativeS3FileSystem`.

Comment: Great stuff Sir

Comment: @bartosz25 thanks for your answer, is very clear and interesting. Would you be able to add link/source to proof what you are affirming?

Comment: You're welcome. You can check the implementation in these Github links: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Globber.java https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala  https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java